# What is the latest version of Unity-2d

Tags: unity-2d

i would like to have the latest version of unity-2d installed on my system.
i can see some references to a version 6 in some places e.g.
http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/u/unity-2d/

but all i can grab from the repos is version 5.14, after that it's related as dummy packages.

i would like to put my hands in the latest unity-2d code available. please help me

Comment: ... deletes answer cuz @braiam was quicker ... comment: latest is 5.14 (and also the last one ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Unity 2D isn't offered package beyond Quantal. You are only seeing the version 5.14 because you are using Precise. All development is focussing on [UnityNext](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnityNextSpec) as noticed by the [wiki page of the project](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity2D):

> Notice: The information on this page is likely to change soon as we switch our development focus to the UnityNext project. For more information about UnityNext, please read [the spec](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity2D).

If you like to have a newer version, either you upgrade to Quantal or wait for UnityNext.